# looping through tridimensional arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have an array of arrays that looks like this:

```
Array
 (
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 39
        [nume] => Ardeleanu
        [prenume] => Bogdan
        [crm] => Array
            (
            )

    )


[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 40
        [nume] => Avram
        [prenume] => Corina
        [crm] => Array
            (
                [2014-02-27] => 2
                [2014-02-28] => 1
            )

    )
)
```

Here is my code :

```
foreach ($newOrders as $crm) {
   foreach ($crm as $angajati) {
      foreach ($angajati['crm'] as $val) {
        echo $val;
      }
   }
}
```

I getting the Warning:

> Illegal string offset 'crm'.

What am I missing ?

Comment: What are you trying to echo? just the crm array? or you want to print everything?

Comment: I need this  [2014-02-27] => 2

Comment: added an answer below. Hope it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it helps ?

```
foreach ($newOrders as $key=>$val) {
 if(array_key_exists("crm",$val) && count($val["crm"]) > 0 ){
   foreach($val["crm"] as $k=>$v){
     echo $k." = ".$v."<br />";
   }
 }
}
```

When we loop through a multi dimentional array its better to check if the keys are available if the corresponding values are again array and also to check if the array of values have some elements before doing loop.

So here first checking if "crm" is available and if the value i.e. again an array having some elements before doing a loop and its done by the line

```
if(array_key_exists("crm",$val) && count($val["crm"]) > 0 ){
```

This is done to avoid further notice like invalid index and invalid argument supplied in foreach if the element is missing or the data array is not present.

Comment: +1. You might also want to explain what you are doing.

Comment: Added the explanation.

Comment: I need the values from 'crm'  [2014-02-27] => 2 ,  [2014-02-28] => 1 for a mysql query. So i need both the key and the value. Your code doesnt display anything :(

Comment: @user3387622 This code works fine [here](https://eval.in/121300), you need to show how your code is different.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to loop over whole 2-nd level array, but only `crm` key points to array. Thus, you need to do:

```
foreach ($newOrders as $crm) 
{
   if(isset($crm['crm']))
   {
     foreach ($crm['crm'] as $val) 
     {
          echo $val;
     }
   }
}
```

-if you want to get values in `crm` key. It may not exist, thus, I've added `isset` check.

Comment: With this I get " Undefined index: crm"

Comment: I've added `isset` check for that